# UNITY3D: assigning same value in a loop is efficient?

Tags: c#, optimization, unity-game-engine

i am coding in C# with Unity3D and have a basic question. The following code snippet appears in the Loop of an Object "Monster"

```
if (monster == ENEMY.DEAD)
    isHidden = true;
    hideMe();
```

Somewhere in the code, i am setting the status of monster, which would in this case execute the written three lines of code all the time.

1) Is the Compiler of Unity clever enough to see, that there is no status change?

2) Or is this a bad way of changing Statuses?

ps: hideMe() is a function which checks if isHidden is set to true, to then disable all objects relevant for this object

Comment: If you ask me, I'd pass the parameter to the function if you need it just for that one method, like "hideMe(monster == ENEMY.DEAD)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No.
2) Yes. Don't do things to other objects. Send events and let the other MonoBehaviours react accordingly. Decouple your code.

Comment: Even when i send messages, like changing the Status. I have to listen in the update for the change. 
Update(){}

Comment: No you don't. Just change what delegates you're running in Update when the events fire.